# What do sinh and cosh have to do with exp?

Tags: exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

My friend told me that $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ result from an exponential function, but I can't figure out why

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Definitions) should answer your question.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Exponential_definitions

Comment: There's nothing to "figure out", just look at the definition.

Comment: The tricky aspect to this question is what definition you're using of the hyperbolic trig functions. In fact, the most obvious definition is in terms of $e^x$ (as Kenny's answer below indicates). By contrast, it's slightly more interesting if you define the hyperbolic functions in terms of differential equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cosh(x) = \frac{1}{2} (\exp(x)+\exp(-x))$$
$$\sinh(x) = \frac{1}{2} (\exp(x)-\exp(-x))$$

$\exp(x)$ is the natural exponential function $\exp(x)=e^x$